# If I use a Mystery Play in Fluxx, does that count as a play?

Tags: fluxx

As far as I know, `Free Action` on a `New Rule` means it doesn't count as a `Play` when used. If I use the `Mystery Play` rule or any of its analogues does it count as a `Play`?

Analogues of `Mystery Play` include (some with slight variations such as conditional requirements for use):

- Wormhole in Star Fluxx
- Magic Shoes in Oz Fluxx
- Egads! in Batman Fluxx
- Open The Door in Monster Fluxx
- Magic Portal in Adventure Time Fluxx
- Chemical X in Cartoon Network Fluxx
- Time Doorway in Regular Show Fluxx
- Great Idea! in Stoner Fluxx

Answer (score 1):

`Free Actions` do not count as a `Play` so `Mystery Play` and its analogues do not count as a `Play` and can be used anytime during your turn either before, during, or after drawing and playing.

Reference: http://faq.looneylabs.com/fluxx-games/faq-for-fluxx-unthemed-versions#723